# Integer Lists of Noah

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, integer

### Introduction:

I think we've all heard of it, but here a very brief summary: Noah gathered two of every species of animal on the planet, male and female, to save in his Ark during a great flood. The actual quote from the Bible is:

> *Genesis 7:2-3*
> You must take with you seven of every kind of clean animal, the male and its mate, two of every kind of unclean animal, the male and its mate, and also seven of every kind of bird in the sky, male and female, to preserve their offspring on the face of the earth.
> [<sup>source</sup>](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen+7%3A2-3&version=NET)

But for the sake of this challenge we will ignore the clean/unclean part and the part where he took seven of each animal. This challenge is only about this part:

> two of every kind of <s>unclean</s> animal, the male and its mate

### Challenge:

**Input:**

You are given a list of positive integers (in random order).

**Output:**

Two distinct values indicating whether it's a 'List of Noah' or not. This doesn't necessary have to be a [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) value, so could also be `0`/`1` in Java/C#, or `'A'`/`'B'` in any language, to give some examples.

When is a list a 'List of Noah'? When there are exactly two of every integer in the list.

### Challenge rules:

- I/O is flexible. Input can be a list/array/stream of integers/floats/strings, or read one by one from STDIN. Output can be any two ***distinct*** values, returned from a function or output to STDOUT / a file.
- The integers in the input-list are in random order, and are guaranteed to be positive within the range \$1\leq n\leq100000\$.
- The input-list is guaranteed to be non-empty.
- Having an integer a multiple of two times present above 2 (i.e. 4, 6, 8, etc.) will be falsey. I.e. `[6,4,4,6,4,7,4,7]` is falsey, although you could still create equal pairs like this: `[[4,4],[4,4],[6,6],[7,7]]`.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Truthy:
[7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9]
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
[10,100,1000,1,100,10,1000,1]
[123,123]
[8,22,57189,492,22,57188,8,492,57188,57189,1,1]

Falsey:
[6,4,4,6,4,7,4,7]
[2,2,2,2,2,2]
[5,1,4,5,1,1,4]
[77,31,5,31,80,77,5,8,8]
[1,2,3,2,1]
[44,4,4]
[500,30,1]
[1,2,1,1]
[2,4,6,4,4,4]
[2,23,34,4]
[2,23,3,3,34,4]
```

Comment: And in Quran also; Surah Al-Mumenoon, Verse 27:
So We inspired him (with this message): "Construct the Ark within Our sight and under Our guidance: then when comes Our Command, and the fountains of the earth gush forth, take thou on board pairs of every species, male and female, and thy family- except those of them against whom the Word has already gone forth: And address Me not in favour of the wrong-doers; for they shall be drowned (in the Flood).
(Yusuf Ali)

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda l:{*map(l.count,l)}=={2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNCoMwDL7vKXZTRxj2x7UKXvcEu80d3B8OahWnBxGf3aVWYR2j5MvPl6RJ6r4tKs2mZ5pNKi@v93yrkmFX5rWv9req0y2oYEzTgY5T3bx063unpmuLPvGCjQ08/bMAwiAGCiRE4EbNIQ7xJfjKI8gymNGNh1gyC8JiLp6bR7GaurUSKIVIEBkDj@nqSJCza21LE9ttKfUyfczV@@FucsCZORgURpyfsPn6nHiEnTkYRO0wQgAjyCBIPIlAEwf7cxL6syg3U7i9IrwGsweZPg)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda l:set(map(l.count,l))=={2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDNDoIwDL77FN6ApDGsDDdMuPoE3tTD/CGYDCQwD8b47LMbGFnM0q8/X9u17Z6mvrdoq/JgtWpOF7XUm@Fq4kZ1sV6d74/WgE6Ssnzh23b9rTXLaNc/TP3cRIvRr@K9AJZBAQgsJeBO@RCH4pj80hiRGXgMwikVeCGYzMkL0pBqMaiUgAi5YLIAXuDXkSC9O9ojzXyvqTI6tFulh2uww5qm5eBQOJl/Q52/bx7OqSsHh6TnhBCQMSIIJF1CkEkz/V8CwwW5GyBolNMNMn8G@wE)

Comment: Cool, didn't know the splat operator worked inside set literals, if I'm interpreting this correctly.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 62 bytes (non-competing)

```python
lambda x:{*[y.count(C)for C	in	(y:=x)]}!={*[2.]}##!2bcdfilmrtu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHLboMwEDyHr9iQC6TbKDZQDBKnfAb1ITGgIBFA1JFAVb6drm0iVcjjnX2MZ8W46PvQR2KcVjVUNRTg@/732l0ft@oKc/57LJeTGp69Di5hM0xw2bX9LljyYg7la19QnZ/k63DY85uqmrZ7TPq5kkaZfzLp1XOtAr8p/A@jHnqekdDQ9lB6UKbIIsyQIzsTxOayqRgziVRnlI3QouNnarGHYAs35uqcurnrFcg5JikTGcYZfxOBwlIXuzLbpoepClQIxqEyDo1jiXAAfa8tgVb/1F1DrV9kMUaDqTl2nN54f5YnJByjQbptJk0xYpQhELRpSiH5@bcp35zERt3NJLRc5PaTuQfj1NKfaAIdIuhw/QM)

Just for fun, a solution that is itself a "List of Noah".

Comment: While fun, this breaks the rules by not being a serious contender.

Comment: It would be great if it were a common rule of this challenge to make code list-of-noahish. Pretty nice twist. I think you can add some extra comment in the title like [list of Noah truthy] to protect yourself from fun fighters and seriosity defenders.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin Good idea.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin There is [very strong consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/43319) to warn non-serious contenders, and then delete if the author has not corrected the answer given reasonable time to do so. Note that this answer actually falls under the label *deliberately invalid*, and wouldn't even require waiting, but we're being unusually nice about this one because it *is* fun.

Comment: @Adám `For code golf, e.g., this is limited to answers that do not even attempt to golf the code. Answers that are simply poorly golfed are not invalid.`
This answer is definitely well golfed and also introduces additional restriction of being list-of-Noah-truthy, which makes it even stronger contender than other solutions. So this rule does not apply here.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin No, removing comments is an obvious way to shorten code, so it isn't well-golfed. And one cannot just make up [tag:restricted-source] requirements on a pure [tag:code-golf] challenge and claim superiority based on that. If the author of this answer wants to do so, they may ask the challenge author to (or for permission to) post such a challenge.

Comment: @negativeseven [*Marking an answer as **non-competing** does not exempt it from being invalid.*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/43319)

Comment: @Adám this applies to rule 2 only.

Comment: @Adám ok, answer is poorly golfed (there's a way to make it shorter), but the attempt to golf it has been done. So Rule 3 does not apply here.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin The author himself [has qualified that rule to be universal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9761/are-non-competing-answers-allowed#comment30559_9761): "The only exception to this rule is using a programming language (or a feature thereof) that was implemented after the challenge was posted." (However, using post-dated languages was later allowed, so there are no more exceptions, afaict.)

Comment: Proposal: [Adding difficulty to the challenge is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10846/87546)

Comment: I think the best way to satisfy everybody: put 2 solutions in one answer, one is competing and follows specs, another is with extra restriction followed.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin But +15/-11 is definitely reliable consensus.

Comment: @Adám IMO, having a self-imposed restricted-source requirement is more akin to using a different language. There _is_ a serious attempt to golf here, but he's not golfing Python 3.8 _per se_, but rather a subset of it governed by the restricted source. I see nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: *Serious contenders do not contain superfluous code* https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10836/34718

Comment: I find the consensus in the link mbomb007 pointed two above clear and have therefore flagged this for deletion.

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
¢<PΘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0CKbgHMz/v@PNtcxNNax1DHSMTQAEiYgCixkomMZCwA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##PU4xDsIwDNx5RdX5kGonxYmE6FIxs1cMIDEwMfAZZp7CA/hSOKctinz22WfnHs/L9X4rosdxaJvtoWmHsXze@9P3VVAmgwRkKKQjRE@1FZHPm0nYC6jorOO4BmEpF@ZTpVJdl6CK3iRlxKwrSUiVzvU8lrq5428RjubBDpfWR9ZTF@HITG6GIOSERLvGksf/drUejX7T1T39Bbf4Aw)

**Explanation**

```
¢      # count all occurrences of each element in the input list
 <     # decrement each
  P    # product
   Θ   # is equal to 1
```

Comment: Ah, I had prepared `¢2QP`, but using `Θ` is also a nice alternative. :)

Comment: Thought I had a 3 with `{ιË`, but of course that fails when integers occur 4 times.

Answer (score 11):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ọtᵛ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@Hu3pKHW2cDWdEWOkZGOqbmhhaWOiaWRjCOhY4FmAthQ6QNdQxjAQ)

#### Explanation

```
ọ           Get the list of occurences of elements in the input: [[x,2], [y,2], …]
  ᵛ         Verify that for each of those pairs…
 t          …the tail (i.e. the number of occurences)
   2        …is 2
```

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to digEmAll by changing the input method

```r
any(table(scan())-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/tCsMgDPy/p@hPhbTUaKfC9jBdWWEwHOwDOsae3Z1WC0NySc47Y@5xPs6vMD0vtyAW@XlMY2gObbNxXdfJJY7hLZ7j6XoWSSCkbFnG724Wk7CkNHliUj3ApJQpQ17KrFDgNWWsTA9ZDkApS1cVDAdXvSNmGqxynozn2jhyuV3r9VptL@zxA0MJbYrCwlxPYQZ4DCVELpy1pBU4gMM6FiWG/a3D2yCT5lTngB10XiP@AA)

Outputs `FALSE` if it is a list of Noah, and `TRUE` otherwise. Works for any input type, not only integers.

Computes the count of each value in the list, and checks whether any of the counts are different from 2.

Comment: You could take input from stdin saving 6 bytes : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/tCsMgDPy/p@hPhbTUaKfC9jBdWWEwHOwDOsae3Z1WC0NySc47Y@5xPs6vMD0vtyAW@XlMY2gObbNxXdfJJY7hLZ7j6XoWSSCkbFnG724Wk7CkNHliUj3ApJQpQ17KrFDgNWWsTA9ZDkApS1cVDAdXvSNmGqxynozn2jhyuV3r9VptL@zxA0MJbYrCwlxPYQZ4DCVELpy1pBU4gMM6FiWG/a3D2yCT5lTngB10XiP@AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks; I misread the challenge rules and thought this was not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>39</s>, 32 bytes

```cs
l=>l.All(x=>l.Count(y=>y==x)==2)
```

Thanks to @Expired_Data

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHBCsIwDL37FcXTBlFs19kO7UBEQfDuQTzoqDCoHeiGivjtM53upKuUvCTtSx5Js8sgu@T1srLZdLWw1Umf9wejp7ktUzgUhUnJkajaqNQMZ8YENxfMi8qWwV2ld6VuoVIsrCe9zTkv9Tq3OjgGVl@3O/IgAmgECTCgIwTuXHPFISHPMPxdRJEaQYMe0gibNYbwCT@Zp4hhX@bpKoExiAWVCfCEtYkE2aTv@P1Mv3X6/Y6uY5yXg0PhrFseFdvTTYpRm4ND9N00ISCiSEOQuHWBIc7xb@vMtz7uxvBIxrj9qP2A@gU)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVHBCsIwDL37FcXTBlFs19kO7UBEQfDuQTzoqDCoHeiGivjtM53upKuUvCTtSx5Js8sgu@T1srLZdLWw1Umf9wejp7ktUzgUhUnJkajaqNQMZ8YENxfMi8qWwV2ld6VuoVIsrCe9zTkv9Tq3OjgGVl@3O/IgAmgECTCgIwTuXHPFISHPMPxdRJEaQYMe0gibNYbwCT@Zp4hhX@bpKoExiAWVCfCEtYkE2aTv@P1Mv3X6/Y6uY5yXg0PhrFseFdvTTYpRm4ND9N00ISCiSEOQuHWBIc7xb@vMtz7uxvBIxrj9qP2A@gU "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVHBCsIwDL37FcXTJlFs19kO3W4KgjcRD@LBjQqF2oE6PIjfPtPNnXSVkpekfckjaXEbFzddrypbLNZLW13U9ZQbtdD2nkFeliYjZ5LWJs3MZFtdgjBNzWRndWkDE7Y3I1bPB/urvquNtio4B1Y9DkfyJAJoBAkwoFME7lxzxSEhrzD8XUSRGkGDHtIUmzWG8Ak/maeIYV/m6SqBMYgFlQnwhHWJBNmkbdw@02@d4bCn6wzn5eBQOOuXR8Xu9JNi1ObgEH0/TQiIKNIQJG5dYIhz/Ns6862PuzE8kjFuP@o@oH4D) 

Comment: My previous comment passes all listed test cases, but fails on cases like `2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4`; disregard 

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
2¨≡⍧⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU4xDsIwDNx5BQ9wJeKkJJ1ZYEKifKBSC0sFDAwwIyGB1AoGHsAEG3/gKflIOaeFFUU@@3y2c9mmjPJ9Vq6XUbHbFqu8yJuG309/uvvq4atns/DHi69qX98mU38@vF/aH69g6WwEnI8nabPoW1KaEmJSA4CRFFqGkt4/VaGnKaCwAeQQgK7smKiMSZY5R8wUW@USMgl/iSMXaFu3sgqbQ/xmSNBKoIOl7wOLMWdIEFk8W9IKHOBg16LE8Z9dDkeN3JTpGP50Z1G0UHH3Id4H)

Is it true that…

`2¨` two for each element

`≡` is identical to

`⍧⍨` the count-in selfie (count of own elements in self)

?

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f x=and[sum[1|b<-x,b==a]==2|a<-x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjYxLyW6uDQ32rAmyUa3QifJ1jYx1tbWqCYRyIv9n5uYmWdbUJSZV6KSFm2oY6hjBIRAOvY/AA)

For each element of the input we ensure it appears twice in the input list.

`sum[1|b<-x,b==a]` is just a golfier version of `length(filter(==a)x)`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 18 bytes

```
{so.Bag{*}.all==2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujhfzykxvVqrVi8xJ8fW1qj2f3FipYKSSryCrZ1CdZqCSnytkkJafpGCjaGdDpBQgFEKRnAGkPkfAA)

- `.Bag` converts the input list to a `Bag`--a set with multiplicity.
- `{*}` extracts all of the multiplicities.
- `.all` creates an and-junction of the multiplicities.
- `== 2` results in another and-junction of Booleans, each true if the multiplicity is 2.
- `so` collapses the junction to a single Boolean.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

Returns *false* for Noah or *true* for non-Noah.

```javascript
a=>a.some(v=>a.map(x=>t-=v==x,t=2)|t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLDsIgELz7Iy3JaoRSoRp69Au8qQeirY/UYiw2mvjvdWltog2GMLvLLLMwZ13ranc7Xe24NPusyVWjVaonlblkYe2yi76GD5XasaqVeoBVjLwsaXamrEyRTQpzCIPV7W6Pz3lAFqPv8zxcC6ARJMCAThG4C@0Rh2RLyLCbYk8ELfrYKV5vN8In/VS@boZKzKcjgTGIBZUJ8IT1hQTZll3e0bRT/hEINuVSF1XmvjtUnuG/ODgUbntm47h@edgYJ3JwiNHDCwERRR5BopECU3z2XyOZ1xju3uhTj9HJqDOzeQM)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>               // a[] = input
  a.some(v =>      // for each value v in a[]:
    a.map(x =>     //   for each value x in a[]:
      t -= v == x, //     decrement t if v is equal to x
                   //     (i.e. if v appears exactly twice, t is decremented twice)
      t = 2        //     start with t = 2
    )              //   end of map()
    | t            //   yield t, which is supposed to be equal to 0
  )                // end of some()
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
[:*/2=#/.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LDsIgELz3KyZ6IBJtYQGhTXoy8eTJq0djY7z4B/46LrRQDeywM7vs4xU3rZgwDhDYQ2FgO7Q4XS/neBtkR@O2az9x16B53J9vTPDQBj0IWjHY9GTJoi8pmgNmxiopvtkYFndhNYVMskIDiOC8Dj1sT4UE1hOd/TmsSw0hpRTl/5Enshl9siLTeorkuILNyG9d08NoFhmCSsxx5/C/Ia3D29Ssfna8l/ldLaUyjV8)

Comment: also 10 bytes: `[:*/2=1#.=` I really want to remove that cap but can’t figure out how.

Comment: @cole when I tried this, I got your solution. If you really wanted to remove the cap you _could_ do `2*/@:=1#.=`, also 10 bytes

Comment: @cole Nice alternative!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Yes, `@:` comes handy here too.

Comment: @GalenIvanov gotta love monadic `=`, so strangely useful in niche golfing scenarios

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns `0`/`1`.

```apl
∧/2=⊢∘≢⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU49iwJBDO39JQoRd7Kzzmxx1TV3FgqunVgIgo2grSxXHRx7iys2gpWFFjb@AH9P/sj6Mn4w5CUvecm86WrRnq2ni@W8rqW4dPhDypMUB/k/yeZW57Ldy9@uKdWWpfwFy4afwNHXd9ZC7mWDvlTHH6nOeQS81mNHJqaUmEwEsJpCy1I6aYwNejEFVBZhHALwLJ9Mpwwlq84TMyXO@JRsyi/iyQf6qB9jEza7@M2SotNAB0uvB5ZAZ0kRGdw5ig04wMOuQ4njb7scjlq9qeoE/mK1eAc)

…`⌸` for each value as left argument and indices of occurrences of that value as right argument, call:

`≢` tally the right argument (the occurrences)
 `∘` then
 `⊢` return that, ignoring the left argument

`2=` Boolean list indicating which tallies are 2

`∧/` AND-reduction (i.e. are they all true?)

Answer (score 4):

## [MS SQL Server 2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-technical-documentation?view=sql-server-2017), <s>152</s> <s>150</s> 146 bytes

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f(@ NVARCHAR(MAX))RETURNS
TABLE RETURN SELECT IIF(2=ALL(SELECT
COUNT(*)FROM STRING_SPLIT(@,',')GROUP BY
PARSE(value AS INT)),1,0)r
```

The readable version:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f(@ NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS TABLE RETURN
  SELECT IIF(2 = ALL(SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@, ',')
                     GROUP BY PARSE(value AS INT)), 1, 0) AS r
```

Try it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dfcbb/1)!

*-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

Comment: Since you don't use the alias, can't the `c` be removed after the `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>61</s> 45 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
all((2==).length).group.sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU67DoMwDNz7FRk6gGQhEkITBraO/QPEkIG2qOEhSL@fngNUkc8@39nx262fzvtt64d5WoK4u@CyR7@Gy7N23ieJqus08934Cu80ey3Td85WGLfB9aOoxbz0YxBXMbhZPEXTGJIFVaRI5gDNKbY0VS01Er2CIjLLIccAHOXBWFVwKvZZUopKI21FulInsWQj3etdlnHyht80MRoOdDB0PrASPk2MyODGUCHBARbnGpRY/j9XxaWad7K7xH3FcSJrqNrtBw)

Thanks to @KevinCruijssen for 12 bytes, and @nimi for another 4.

First Haskell answer, but it was surprisingly easy to do. Can <s>probably</s> be golfed a lot. *Case in point...*

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but I'm pretty sure `all(True==).map(2==)` can be `all(2==)`. :)

Comment: ... and move `length` to `all`: `all((2==).length).group.sort`. No need to give the function a name, i.e. drop the `f=`.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the `all(2==)` when I was testing in GHCi. Thanks Kevin and Nimi, I'll update the answer.

Comment: ... oh and for future use: `all(True==)` is `and`.

Answer (score 4):

### TI-Basic, 47 Bytes

```
Input(L1
SortA(L1
not(remainder(dim(L1,2)) and prod(not(△List(L1))=seq(remainder(I,2),I,1,-1+dim(L1
```

I am a big of fan of TI-Basic. It's not a great language for really any purpose, but I enjoy programming (and golfing) in it.

How does this code work?

First, it sorts the list.

Second, it uses the △List function to generate another list, which is the difference between elements of the sorted list. (For example, △List({1,3,7,8}) would yield {2,4,1}).  Applies not to this list, which converts every non-zero element of the list to zero and every zero to one.

Then, the program checks that the resultant list fits the pattern `{1, 0, 1, 0, ...}`, which will only be true if the original list is a Noah list.

There is also an additional check that the length of the list is even, to catch some edge cases.

Here are some screenshots of test cases:

[image: Some test cases]
[image: Some more test cases]

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), <s>30 characters</s> 26 bytes

```
!a=all(x->2==sum(a.==x),a)
```

Thank you, H.PWiz for this trick!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5JDsIwDLz3FXAr0lARJyXpIf1IxSEXJFBBiEXqgQfwBN7HR4rtpkIoysQzHsdzfPSHZIZxH8dliqnvy2HdUoy3x6lMVYzDCmk1dkXnYSwaEMyGwcmjkkOzQ9EZFi0UlW7YoJchl5lpm9hL6gwgQu1NaOAamklAUDrVU9vobNFteaeDoJcrn/DcfITW7HUQ5FcE72ENCwyBc3suecMvN02xnHysAzUntXNYaU8l5cXZxess7B9BFordonq2i8v1cL7358/rvR@/)

Comment: You can have `!a=all(x->2==sum(a.==x),a)` for 26 bytes. NB. that I recommend counting in bytes on this site

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know you could (ab)use `!` for anonymous functions

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Qœ^Ƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU6xDQIxDOwzyxUfJyHJGJQoejoa9AvQ0lAj1mALBIOwSDg7/0KRz77z2fH5tCyX3vfvx/Fz76/b9/o89N5cy/ABFQI/EaImkyLqDNc8xQBDoxMNFoS1XJm1hV4xZ4EIUvalIlbZSEExOurR9mN2xy8jFLOGShzbntJEa4Qiswo5I3gKhMKzM0t@8D9bxuaoi20g8dCgt7r5Bw)

```
Q       Is the list of unique elements
   Ƒ    unchanged by
 œ^     symmetric multiset difference with the whole input?
```

In broader terms, "if you remove each unique element once, do you have one of each left?" This is guaranteed to stay in the right order because `œ^` is implemented as equivalent to `œ-œ|œ-@`, `Qœ-` is just empty, and `œ-` [specifically removes elements last-first](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/70c9fd93ab009c05dc396f8cc091f72b212fb188/jelly/interpreter.py#L644) while `Q` is in the order of first appearances.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```matlab
@(x)any(sum(x==x')-2)
```

Anonymous function that inputs a numeric vector, and outputs `0` if the vector satisfies the condition or `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzMa9So7g0V6PC1rZCXVPXSPN/mka0uY6hsY6ljpGOoQGQMAFRYCETHctYzf8A) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RVDLCoMwELz7FbnVwFZMjE2kBPofUoqInqw9qMVS@u12NmpL2NmdfQ551GP1bJbWJ0myXOJZVv0rHqZ7PHs/H@RRy2VshvFWV0MzCC/epSWVUUGaVAow7ELKUHEVpUIuo4DMUpSDAbZwY1zV6NTc50hryq1yBZlC78SRC3SN17LiSWiNyhMuGmK0bNiCwf2B5eg1xAgPbi1lChzgINkixIGfZB0kGd7J3Tk0Zizzc47qpuvaqY9bEv@/kMsX).

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(x)                   % define anonymous function with input x
            x          % x
               x'      % x transposed and conjugated
             ==        % equality comparison, element-wise with broadcast. Gives a
                       % square matrix
        sum(     )     % sum of each column
                  -2   % subtract 2, element-wise
    any(            )  % true if and only if any value is not zero
```

Answer (score 3):

## [VDM-SL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/overturetool/documentation/master/documentation/VDM10LangMan/VDM10_lang_man.pdf), 64 bytes

```cs
f(a)==forall y in set inds a&card{x|x in set inds a&a(x)=a(y)}=2
```

---

#### Explanation

VDM works predominantly like second order logic statements.

```cs
forall y in set inds a                //Bind y to each of the indices of a

{x|x in set inds a&a(x)=a(y)}         //build a set of the indices of a who have the same
                                      //value as the value at y

card {...} = 2                        //and check the cardinality of that set is 2
```

---

#### Since you can't TIO VDM here's output from a debug session

[image]

Comment: I know there probably isn't any online compiler for it, but could you perhaps add some screenshots of (some of) the test cases as verification? :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen saved some bytes fixing the bug, which probably made the code itself easier to understand. I'll add an explanation too :)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> <s>37</s> 26 bytes

<sup>-11 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
!(($args|group|% c*t)-ne2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/RboMwDHzPVzCVLrC5UmNCEx72LVM1hbYTKhW0WqXSb2fnANrTFPnssx37fGl/QtcfQ9OMaf3xGF@yLN13h344dO3tMqyTr7drvjkHzsenUqtrdwsqc2QKqojJbAFWXExZqnJSmUGyoIiRbtEQDTCHM4tlRi/HTk/MVDrjK7IVL8STj3SKpzLm5MP6oV/TOtHv6efmuz2ddaKHU7g/ldZqVe@bHlJ3EGVJ0InJFgxentASwywJwkvCOSoMEgCPwxxCSPg7jCfdVgbHDyVOKZZrpDyFPC@Wrn@1jr8)

Groups up `$l` and grabs all the counts of matching values. It then filters out all counts of 2 from this list. If the list is empty, it's a Noah number; otherwise, it'll be populated still with non-2 counts. Not-ing the list will yield `True` if it's empty and `False` if it's populated

Comment: Fails if the values balance each other out.. i.e [1,2,1,1] so the count is 4, the count of unique is 2 and hence will resolve as noah despite not being noah.

Comment: @ExpiredData Heck

Comment: I tried this approach in another language before realising it just won't work...

Comment: @ExpiredData Okay, now it should work on account of doing something completely different.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ [26](https://tio.run/##fU/RDoIwDHzfV2BEB1oTNoYbD36LMWYohggBjCbit@NtaHwzy669trtdm/pu2@5sq2oMi91znEVReGhP3XBq61szLILjqo83Vyvj8cXYvG9vlkWaREo5SRIJQLngS4rymFgkUEzJo6cJBvwFfNIP822JWeknDUlJmRYmJ5XLLzFkPJ3yqQ2deFg8@TIsAr4O95tLXV55wIfSPl6MczYvDlUHq1uYUuRQu@t@gfD3OJpBTJFDRFfQmlKBAsBgMY0UFn6Lycm3csL@QYZV0uSfo/EN "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Thanks. Forgot all about `group` being a thing that exists

Answer (score 3):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```elixir
fn v->Enum.all?v,fn x->2==Enum.count v,&x==&1end end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLDoIwELz7FZyMJiuhS7HlUD158OQHGA9GISHBahQIf4/TihepaXb2Mdvpdou66qvnUJqhtFG32uxse4vPdb3tCIV@tWFjfO1yb20TdTTvjZmLwl4j2LA/xJV9PYpLE5Xx4qhIpJQTk0gA0jlfkpSflrOfZoGWlDwGyASXvQHGcMwCzQwdDqhoYqZMCZ2TzPmbaNI@/cQfWnjd3/trTC7JoXI2fQCa3zMlM6hKcgg/pZWiVIAGaOxJIcRk//bEoY9LN15AOsOe0vCqnFCI4PGjXm94Aw)

Complete Elixir noob here :-D.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 60 bytes

```php
function($a){return!array_diff(array_count_values($a),[2]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVHRaoQwEHz3K7big8LCXaJXFXv0Q6xI8BK8ckSJsVCO@3a7iZESMpndzGZndR7n7eNzHucoSqxc7AJXaCOAtkSWY40c2ZmgcIdPFVh3CHA6gTWrdEpG9zl67NAnzqT2myDQEAUBJz0P6go5x0vJqhqLmh9BhZUPd75fM1/vat7JRoEOS7fJEPlR4rF4Q/TIsfYWFyot0CGde6osMWeUIqhospIotQz2/ED8cFu4XqHsQkPk/3M40RHw4Mhpo66h76nguqlVD/Y@6TQR2dNIuxr9JowRv/3trlS602Fate1/xGOVixNiy7useW30iJqMFMOYQvg7YiEGGTyppRzGCb6XSfdSD9NNponNEOIv61aMkKgjo@Mmem1/)

PHP has great built-ins for this, though at 20 chars, `array_count_values()` is not a very golfy one.

Comment: PHP always has great built-ins, with long names, sigh!

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
MatchQ[{{_,2}..}]@*Tally
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7BCsIwDL33KzxLmGva2e4g7AcEBW8iUoZjg82D7CKl3z6TdENKX/KSl@RNYe5fU5iHNizd7rScw9z213uMT8BUFOnR7G9hHL/L5TO852bfHZqoogNtoAYEXRJYDlKyUCdQUVPRgKDQkgTyCdZ0ZdJG0qIoPSBC5bSvwda4EQ9eaM5zW8usike6aYHR8eclNLc9phVpLTBS5IJzYDQVCDz5dpTShb9vzLYsL5aBipyazSy3c4rrYVaptPwA)

The `Tally` function returns a list of the form `{{element, count}, ...}`, which is then matched against a pattern that checks whether all *count* are 2.

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 16 bytes

```
${All&x!{_~x=2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/BCsIwDL3vKyYMTznYrLOdIEO8iwdvY8jQToUhYisoMn99pt26aUtf816TNK80pjycVVuFi2UbvVd1PX1O3vvPc4lN026UOuo8ut0OpyLY3i9Xs1ParEutdF5BmAchrSwLzf1hzi/HcgEshhQQ2IyA28tJHNICuhRGDzE4HKQZJbpD0Ic9G1KQanCokIAIiWAyBZ6iJxKko13cPTPXw89albVW/axzmoqDRWGPb03d/PZSQl04WKTbi0JAzEgkkORSUEj//7vE0QC3nw3FCXmLf@3Z1JFiP5itCIqi/QI)

### Explanation

```
${All&x!{_~x=2}}
${             }    lambda with input x
  All&x!{     }     over each element _ of x:
         _~x            check that the number of occurrences of _ in x
            =2          is 2
```

### Alternatives

**17 bytes:** `` {All&_!`=&2@`~&_} ``

**18 bytes:** `` {All[`=&2@`~&_,_]} ``

**23 bytes:** `` Same@2&`'@Sum@Table[`=] ``

**25 bytes:** `` Same«2'Sum@Table[`=,_]» ``

**25 bytes:** `` Same<~2'Sum@Table[`=,_]~> ``

**25 bytes:** `` {Same[2'Sum@Table[`=,_]]} ``

**35 bytes:** `{Commonest@_==Unique@_and _[0]~_=2}`

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

**Solution:**

```
&/2=#:'.=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X03fyFbZSl3P1lzB0FjBUsFIwdAASJiAKLCQiYLl//8A)

**Explanation:**

```
&/2=#:'.= / the solution
        = / group
       .  / value
    #:'   / count (length of) each
  2=      / equal to 2?
&/        / take minimum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
l->sum(isone,l./l')/length(l)==2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHNTsMwDMfvfYpol7WS2ZqPkvRQxIkn2A1xGCLtikKQlkSCpy9OP4QqltIqjlP/bNf/vAfTn@nXEFxvO3LSzmdtM5i7Bxc@8t59Wg3mcDT74mi07fwlN0XTsOHRI@m0J7vTNfjL94686q63GcFnjJE2f5ZAOdTAgJZoRNzGTwLql4I0DfHXoNcpFEEOo00iJRYaF5rZnU/JFIY1WbKiAsagklTVIGq2HBSo8Tj5U5iuemj7lv0K8XQ2Tt8W4h5HFhCtjGsq0UZ@zWHv5U0yFf6EgGhxT1JSAqdIoVGoukQX50nik@xsme4GIeIE6X4Vys/LjfzYgW7E2SzQVhOUhQP/n4C/FF7V8AM)

Divides each element of the input array `l` by the transpose `l'` giving a matrix. Summing over this matrix while applying `isone` to each element gives twice the length of `l` if each element appears exactly twice.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
2==##&@@Counts@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCsIwELz3NwI9rdhsUpMcKgF/wLt4KGKxh1bQeCr99ribpIiEzO7Mzj6mPjzuUx/GWx@HLmLXCVF7f3p@5vD2oo7n1ziHi9gdBy@u9d4v1WJAKnCAIBsCzSFJGtwK1SJJVJAw0YYM6ROUtLBURvJiclpAhNZI60A73IgFm2jOc1nm3gOt1MBo@LNEbdtj2pJVAyNFFowBJUkgsHS2oZQW/M7GPFnz4NTQ0qFqu5XLOcWyuLhonQL1R6AI1Rq/)

`Counts` returns an association of `<| (value)->(# occurences), ... |>`. Then `2==##&` checks if those occurence-counts are all equal to 2.

Comment: `2==##&@@` is brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
oĉŤđ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVA7DsIwDBUrp6gyu1LzKUnOUnUoqCwIOrQcgpGZpUMRDByjXILT8JykCEV5fs9-sa3cnqf20B2boXlVIj8KykTeinq8n4d97h7dfHlP83Xqt7s-5cbPKqssSU2eFMkCYDiElCFfryuJnKaArAqUwwUkmhRXFZyKfY6UotJK58l4tQhHLsjIY1mGlxtMM8Ro-SKDR8uBKuEzxIgIbS1pCQ1wWNeCovlvXRWaGu7J7hL76bQi1wJTaWC0YIwm_c8p6fhTXw)

```
oĉŤđ
o       Sort
 ĉ      Split into runs of equal elements
  Ť     Transpose; fails if not rectangular
   đ    Check if length is 2
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
oĭu=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVAxDsIwDBQrr6gyuxJxUpIMvKTqUFBZUOnQ9jUsHajEAL_gFbyGc5oiFOV8Z19sK7fHtbl0bT3Uz1LlraJM5Y2qpnkczrmfu_drPNz746lPmemzyUpH2lAgJr0DWAkxZSlU21IjZyiiqB3K8QISTUqqDCeLzxMzFU77QDbwKjz5KBe-lHV8ucc0S4JOLjJ4tB6oAj5LgojQzpHR0ACPdR0omv_W5djUSk9xF9jPpBWlFhmngYsFYwyZf05JLz_1BQ)

```
oĭu=
o       Sort
 ĭ      Uninterleave
  u     Uniquify
   =    Check equality
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
Ţ≡2=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVAxDsIwDBQrr6gyu1LjpCQdeEnVoaCyoMLQ8gjewFIQCAa-wScYeQnnNEUoyvnOvthWTo9ds923dV8_S5W2ihKVNqoabod-k_r76_I5nnl57VbrLuaG9ywpHWlDBTHpDGAlhJSlopqXGjlDAUVlKIcLiDQqqTKcLD5PzJQ77QuyBU_Ckw9y5GNZh5cLTLMk6OQig0fTgcrhsySICO0cGQ0N8FjXgaL5b10OTa30FHeO_UxcUWqBcRw4WjDGkPnnFPX4U18)

```
Ţ≡2=
Ţ       Tally; produces a list of unique elements and a list of their counts
 ≡      Check if all counts are equal, and return that value
  2=    Check if equal to 2
```

Comment: Nice answer! For a moment I was confused why you had a `đ - Check if length is 2` builtin, but I saw it's actually an unpair builtin, which as side effect fails if the length isn't 2. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Elm 0.19, 66 bytes

```elm
n a=List.all(\x->List.foldl(\y c->if x==y then c+1 else c)0 a==2)a
```

Verify all test cases [here](https://ellie-app.com/62XcGPK4CGna1).

For every item, iterate over the list and count how many items it is equal to. Return `True` if the count is exactly 2 for each item, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
!n#2/LQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzFP2UjfJ/D//2gzHRMgBJHmIBwLAA)

```
!n#2/LQQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
           Trailing Q inferred
     L Q   For each element of Q...
    / Q    ... count its occurrences in Q
  #        Filter keep those elements...
 n 2       ... which are not equal to 2
!          NOT - maps [] to True, others to False
           Implicit print
```

Comment: Another 7-byte solution is `!smtt/Q`

Comment: @RK Unfortunately.that one fails for input `[1,2,2,2,3,4]` :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ĠẈ=2Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7BDcIwDPxnig5gpMZJSaIK9kBRn3xQF@BX8SlDgNQBWIA@@JRF2kWC7bRCkc@@89nx5dy215S@wzzeDziPQ5rfn3rpHsXuWCzds556NfXL7XVKKaroQBsIgKBLAstJJAuhARU1iQYEhZZkkCBYy5VJG8mL4vSACJXTPoANuBEPXmiuc1vn2T19aYHRcbBEY9tjWpHVAiNlFpwDo0kg8HS2o5I@@J@NebPlxTJQ0aGGb1XNDw)

A monadic link that takes a list of integers and returns 1 if a Noah list and 0 if not.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
8#uqqa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30K5tLAw8f//aHMFQ2MFSwUjBUMDIGECosBCJgqWsQA)

0 for truthy, 1 for falsy. Ports [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187887/67312).

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
&=s2=A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8222MjW8f//aHMFQ2MFSwUjBUMDIGECosBCJgqWsQA)

1 for truthy, 0 for falsy. Ports [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187884/67312).

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>96</s> <s>77</s> <s>69</s> 51 bytes

```
fun f(t:List<Int>)=t.count{t.count{i->it==i}!=2}==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LasMwEDwnXzE1PViHOrbzDpGhx0JvvfYigpyIOJKx1i3F@NvVtZ1CKIu0Ozszu9LVUWVsCGVrUcZ0eDeejm@WCiEpObnWUveXzUthSErTP8m8lzIdPTdlbKyasz/gtWnUz/GDGmPPhUA3n89K12BgYSwG0dSdLRbsqz20Ol3A6zXIQbGIGHnCYNPKa7gSLafvi7Yg7Ykns/1LVaytW4Icpia@rgzFESKR8NgOhhJy/IdYoB/W1fwi5p@7Mh5tov@0kWCG2T6ELMUeO2yxwRorLJEje2xu@N4xytKpO1b/9Bw5VyuONTPbMOH7fUfjCVnOnXz5qPgF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.all?{|e|a.count(e)==2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7tCsIwDPzvUwxRUIjDZp3tfkwfZAypUj9gqOhUZO7Z56VOKbnkcpc01/vm1e3ybrZ0jYtdVa2at3@7eHu@n@qJn@Y5t213uR5PdTQcpzfArvAPV01G62lJ0WgdPQ/Hykd7X9@6wpBKKCMmNQdoSaGlKSsHhUIvoYDC5pBDAPqyZ6IynCw@S8yUGmUz0hn/iCUb6Lf@yipMLvCbJkEjgQ6Gfg8shU@TIDK4MZQocIDFuQYllv/P5bBUy05xp7gv6U8ULVTcfyiWDw)

Answer (score 2):

### Excel, 45 bytes

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)=2,1))=COUNT(A:A)/2
```

Assumes data in column A, with this entered in any cell other than one in column A.
Returns TRUE if there are pairs and FALSE if they are not matching pairs

```
        FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)                     Counts how many of each value there is
     IF(                  =2,1)                If this is 2, add value of 1 to array otherwise 0
=SUM(                          )               Sum the count in that array that have a exactly 2
                                 COUNT(A:A)/2  Count how many total values in column
                                =              If this is equal, return TRUE else FALSE
```

Tried removing the /2 and adding .5 for the summing, but this did not work.
Tried counting the frequencies that are <>2 and this did not return the right amount.

Answer (score 2):

[Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-6) (5.1), <strike>20</strike> 48* Bytes:

I setup my variables like this (which may not be correct):

```
 $a = (7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9)
```

I then add that variable to:

```
$a |group|%{$m=@{}}{$m[$_.Name]=($_.Count)-eq2}{$m}
```

This outputs the "Name" and "True" or "False" 
(could also use the animals names & it would work)

- group - Groups the items
- % - Abbreviation for For-Each
- $m=@{} - Assigns the new variable
- $_.Count-eq2 - Item count that equals 2
- $y - List each item with True or False (if it equals 2)

Results are similar to this:

[image: Output]

*Note: This answer has been edited as I bungled things <strike>the first</strike> multiple time*s*...

Comment: I think that screenshot is from a different challenge? :S Could you perhaps post a screenshot with some of the test cases for this challenge as verification?

Comment: [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) requires that the code should be "programs or functions". For Powershell, this means that the code can be saved as a file with the `.ps1` extension and executed as a script. Your code is a snippet, not "programs or functions".

Comment: Sorry, I bungled this one. I reused my variables so it appeared my code was working great. I may have misunderstood the variables as well. I am updating my answer again now.

Comment: I edited my post and it should work now. I think I can make it a bit smaller if I set it up differently and use the original $a variable & remove the need for the $m. I just don't have time to work it out right now...

Comment: A few things: Your current code is 51 bytes, [here's some examples on how to make your code take proper arguments](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXNtppLJbEovbgmvSi/tKBGtVol19ahurYWSEerxOv5JeamxtpqAFnO@aV5JZq6qYVGILlarlouLpV0oO6CxKLEXA2VPE0ulTyyDMmAOSHaIJZ0A/6rqaQpKJgrGBorWCoYKRgaAAkTEAUWMlGw5FJX51JTSVfQMNcxNNax1DHSMTQAEiYgCixkomOpCVGUgV/RfwA "PowerShell – Try It Online"), and lastly: your code stops one step short of finishing the problem. You have all the bools you need, still need to reduce it into one `true/false` return. Good first attempt though!

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26 bytes

Exit code is nonzero iff the list is of Noah.

```bash
sort|uniq -c|grep -v ' 2 '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi/qKSmNC@zUEE3uSa9KLVAQbdMQV3BSEH9/39zcy5jQy5TEGFhwAXkmXJZcFkAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 53 bytes

```
: f ( s -- ? ) dup counts [ last ] map [ 2 = ] all? ;
```

Unfortunately dosn't work in TIO. Here's a screenshot of the [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) Listener (REPL):

[image: Lists-of-Noah Factor Listener]

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```
lambda l:all(l.count(i)==2for i in l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNCoMwDL7vKbypEIb9ca2C1z3BbnOH7kdW6FScHnz6LrUK6xglX5IvP03Sz@Oza5ltqtoa9breVWRKZUxi9rduasdEp1VFm26IdKTbyKS2HzTS8WmYxudcxunOE01yFkAYFECBZAjcqYXiUFzSrzyCUQYLhnyGJYsgrObqhXkUq2lYK4FSyAWRBfCCbo4Eubje9mHiu62lcd0elXk/wk0OODMHh8JJ8BM2317A59iZg0PUQUQIYAQjCBJPItDEwf6chP4syt0UYa8cr8H8QewH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ċⱮ=2P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96ON62yNAv7//x9trmNorGOpY6RjaAAkTEAUWMhExzIWAA)

Not shorter than, but different than the existing jelly answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>358</s> 299 bytes

```
/|/\/\///`/'\\|&/%`\%`\%T;`\%R;N`\%T;`\%|:/\\\\|;/`\`\|_/%%|%/`/|%<-::>:::|QT/%R'N%Q'T_<-;>%<-;;>;;_<`->%_L`S%L'S_-` *%-`{*[_-`{*%{-_!`{%{!_^`{*%^{-_[`*%*[_-`*%*-_!`*%*!_-`[%[-_!`[%[!_{`[%!_^`!%^-!_-`$%$_-`!!`$%$_-`!$&0_!`!!$&0_^`$&1_Q`T%Q'T%R'N|RN/QT|<-:>/<-::>::|<\->/|!*/!-|-*/--|LS/^!DATA GOES HERE$|Q\T/QT/RN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5BboQwDPwKljBIkSy31wTlBQgJyI2IuIdKPfTGEf@dOnR3W8fxeDxxNMf3x/H1eVwXK2c7zMJ9ztoxSq6ZgpUlTM9WPWcLDSxZshZGVLQlxYG8j957nRPj0k8496kMFKIpIcQQyiAUsYyy4tivhaRxSHK6rdSKJxWQE08oe6W78U0c3rJBVQ3A2IZbZQZQToO6AbhT1VpsrQI8m7Z7s6dw4y5t915mSdVatajLxHNScx75YV@HTJEVHAMpOSbSceUdXI3mvs2rd/@mv/k3bXXOyX7nZbquHw)

[Try it online! (legible-ish version)](https://tio.run/##jZHBasUgEEX3fsUTAgOCTLuVR77gYUnipkSELgpddJdl8u/pnVFTXlc1Ue@ZcSbEu31/bF@f23myYbwHZzwQgTMGBPHdhzCGEABTYmOIZ4rEEyXSLGXKYxcVmtA8ZT@KkMIH5UXWpSIqbk633a1XaEdo90BiCwJYhVJTRXPglTJQC7VO4CoTsFdLnFmvlEBL7UoN0B@q@N@ygXjo3a39w1CR8lvvap8CRQ@/6@9Ks6r0RjBTv55ZtvgUetX62ug/51/qBybKqXkCd8wxR5h1wLqx@3fcYQSsNWwdWw83vWMv@2PhYp2MW5t1HeTwlJPYPsfz/AE)

I don't know if this is the first Code Golf answer which uses an actual computational loop in slashes, but I'm very proud of it regardless. The loop construction I use is due to Ørjan Johansen, and is elaborated on on the wiki (although not in very high detail, and he uses `|` instead of `'`). There is a whole lot of escaping involved.

Input is in the form of a string which replaces `DATA GOES HERE` in the source code. The string should be a -delimited list of unary numbers with `*` representing one. Output is `1` if the list is a list of Noah, `0` if it is not.

### Explanation

- The program revolves around the manipulation of the input string, which is prefixed by `^!` and suffixed by `$`. First, the following two substitutions are made: `/!*/!-/` and `/-*/--/`, which turn the first number of the input into dashes. It will be the number line for recording the whole list.
- The rest of the program is inside a loop (not presented in the same order as in the program). First, it organizes the data

```
/- */-\{*[/ /[*/*[/    turn the next number into a "rocket"
                       eg `^!--- **` => `^!---{**[`
/-{*/{-/               the front of the rocket moves forward by "using up fuel"
/!{/{!/                moving forward through a `!` does not cost any fuel
/-*/*-/ /!*/*!/ /-[/[-/ /![/[!/
                       the rest of the rocket follows the head
/^{*/^{-/              the rocket extends the number line if it runs out of room
/{[/!/                 once the rocket runs out of fuel, it becomes a `!`
```

- Since a rocket travels a number of `-`s equal to the number it came from, the result is a backwards number line where every member of the original list is marked with `!`s, eg `^!*** ** *** *****$` => `^!--!!-!--$`
- When the last number turns into a rocket, the `$` begins inspecting the number line:

```
/^!/^-!/                 needed for some of the following to work
/-$/$/ /-!!$/$/          the inspector finds things satisfactory so far
/-!$/N\O/ /!!!$/N\O/     the inspector has rejected this input
/^$/Y\S/                 the inspector has accepted this input
```

- The loop works by replacing a "variable" `RN` with a copy of the relevant code. The simplest way to stop the loop and output the result is to conditionally replace RN with the result so that the loop can't continue. We do this by replacing `YS` and `NO` *with a replacement* that replaces RN with the relevant value: `/YS/\/\/T\\\/R\\N\/T\\\/1/ /NO/\/\/T\\\/R\\N\/T\\\/0/`. (It is `//f/r` instead of `/f/r/` because the `YS` and `NO` values already exist inside a replacement, so it becomes works like, eg, `/LS/YS/` => `/LS///RN/1/`

### Notes

Variables are two letters because you have to be able to escape them by putting a `\` in the middle (`/V\R/val/` is equivalent to `/VR/val/`), otherwise they'll replace themselves in the copy that's used for looping.

At the beginning of the program are several "golfing substitutions" which serve no purpose other than to make the program shorter and even less legible.

59 bytes saved by using direct replacement instead of `YS` and `NO`, and doing 2 more golfing substitutions (`&` for the replacement-replacement which is nearly the same for accepting and rejecting, and `` ` `` for `'\`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
vO2J≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwidk8ySuKJiCIsIiIsIls3LDEzLDksMiwxMCwyLDQsMTAsNywxMyw0LDldXG5bMSwyLDMsMSwyLDNdXG5bMTAsMTAwLDEwMDAsMSwxMDAsMTAsMTAwMCwxXVxuWzEyMywxMjNdXG5bOCwyMiw1NzE4OSw0OTIsMjIsNTcxODgsOCw0OTIsNTcxODgsNTcxODksMSwxXVxuWzYsNCw0LDYsNCw3LDQsN11cblsyLDIsMiwyLDIsMl1cbls1LDEsNCw1LDEsMSw0XVxuWzc3LDMxLDUsMzEsODAsNzcsNSw4LDhdXG5bMSwyLDMsMiwxXVxuWzQ0LDQsNF1cbls1MDAsMzAsMV1cblsxLDIsMSwxXVxuWzIsNCw2LDQsNCw0XVxuWzIsMjMsMzQsNF1cblsyLDIzLDMsMywzNCw0XSJd)

Makes a list of how many times the integer exists in the list, adds `2` to the list and checks if everything is equal. A sneaky way to check if all the items are equal, **and** that they are all 2.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJnIiwiIiwidk8yPSIsIiIsIls3LDEzLDksMiwxMCwyLDQsMTAsNywxMyw0LDldIl0=) for 4 bytes, or [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJnPSIsIiIsInZPMj0iLCIiLCJbNywxMyw5LDIsMTAsMiw0LDEwLDcsMTMsNCw5XSJd) for 3 bytes using Vyncode

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 32 bytes

```factor
[ histogram [ 2 = ] assoc-all? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLTsQwDLz3K@YHWDWPkhaEOCIuXBCn1R6iKrDV9kUSDmi1314cN11AqceesWNb6btt4@SXt9fnl6c7DDYedyHa2IXYtQE2hIncyfnR9Zi9i/F79t0YEdznlxtbF3BfFOfiDAOh0EBClAQ6OZY0iRfKC1JVRuYlfWwEOdwY56ViS3ENKVEZUTfQjdxITXqia7ymBd@mK7c0WDMattRG/jmJV1SsGZNPijFQghSCukysQpryu7/M22nN/bkLrayuW3OFyON0XkNv4xXUf4arcimWPY707tOHtwP2VPCAw/oHbmzfP@KwDHbGDm3vrF9@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{*(2=#'.=x)^1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rW0jCyVVbXs63QjDOs5eJKizZUMFIwVgCTsShcExDXXMHQWMESyDM0AAmBKLCQiYIlqmqYEQAWvhPa)

This one is a little bit lengthier than it needs to be though. Return `0N` (i.e. null) for true and `0` for false.

Explanations:

```
{*(2=#'.=x)^1}  Main function. Takes x as input
  (      x)     x
        =       Group. Returns a dictionary with the keys being the values
                that appear in the array, and the values being the position
                of the corresponding key.
       .        Get just the value
     #'         Get the length for each of them
   2=           See if it's equal to 2
            ^1  Eliminate 1s in the result (i.e. remove truthy values)
 *              Get the first element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
c⁻pḅ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK5IfNe4ueLijdUlxUnIxVHDBbnMdQ2MdSx0jHUMDIGECosBCJjqWECUA)

Port of Emigna's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
c⁻pḅ  # Implicit input
c     # Counts of each element
 ⁻    # Decrement each
  p   # Product of this list
   ḅ  # Equals one?
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
⬤θ⁼²№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMxJ0ejUEfBtbA0MadYw0hHwTm/FCgMFMrUBALr//@jo811DI11LHWMdAwNgIQJiAILmehYxsb@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `-` for a List of Noah. Explanation:

```
 θ      Input array
⬤       Do all elements satisfy the condition
    №   Count of
      ι Current element
     θ  In input array
  ⁼     Equals
   ²    Literal 2
        Implicitly output
```

Comment: Whoa, that's one very charcoal circle.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
O`\d+
(\d+)(,\1)*\b
$#2
^1(,1)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xDsIwDEV3X4MipfCHOnFJcgJGLlChgmBgYUC9f/hJW0V@9ncc5//ey@f7KEd3ncttnl5ncUTvMGl/mp7SHbzc1YGqKyVCAzI8dCCsptYyZFF2AhqFfR1aEFu5KVHPKR8kwXuMUVOGZb@LhNTkWq/X3CAX/mGojDWED/YjIycMlcwSI4JSEYn2Iksu3ezRuVjdZDLSTaChPw) Link includes test cases. Explantion:

```
O`\d+
```

Sort the integers. (This is a string sort but it doesn't matter assuming no leading zeros.)

```
(\d+)(,\1)*\b
$#2
```

Count the number of duplicates of each integer.

```
^1(,1)*$
```

Each integer should have one other duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

Outputs `false` for true and `true` for false.

```
ü mÊdÍ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CBtymTN&input=WzcsMTMsOSwyLDEwLDIsNCwxMCw3LDEzLDQsOV0) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CBtymTN&input=WwpUcnV0aHk6Cls3LDEzLDksMiwxMCwyLDQsMTAsNywxMyw0LDldClsxLDIsMywxLDIsM10KWzEwLDEwMCwxMDAwLDEsMTAwLDEwLDEwMDAsMV0KWzEyMywxMjNdCls4LDIyLDU3MTg5LDQ5MiwyMiw1NzE4OCw4LDQ5Miw1NzE4OCw1NzE4OSwxLDFdCgpGYWxzZXk6Cls2LDQsNCw2LDQsNyw0LDddClsyLDIsMiwyLDIsMl0KWzUsMSw0LDUsMSwxLDRdCls3NywzMSw1LDMxLDgwLDc3LDUsOCw4XQpbMSwyLDMsMiwxXQpbNDQsNCw0XQpbNTAwLDMwLDFdCl0tbVI)

```
ü mÊdÍ     :Implicit input of integer array
ü          :Group by value
  m        :Map
   Ê       :  Length
    d      :Any truthy (not 0)?
     Í     :  When subtracted from 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 38 bytes

```
Gather@#~Cases~{_,_}~Total~2==Total@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LCoMwELz3MxR62oN52CQFIdBDrz30LqEoFfoAzU3Mr6ebqDWlhJ3szm4mO09j783T2O5mfHus/DnUvc7dyQzN4MYa6sld39Y8HK2qmOh87y9997K61aMAwkABBVIg8HBFioOadt8pgj0GEVO2wPEYCEu6VOkUxZc0fSeBUigFkQq4omshQcZyzuc22ZSybBM44HocAooQiTSqrSdhSxTiEBDvhBcCGEEeQaJvgSlu8eeb/vjh4e9UpUTDLHj2Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é♪Ccv
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=820d436376&i=[7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9]%0A[1,2,3,1,2,3]%0A[10,100,1000,1,100,10,1000,1]%0A[123,123]%0A[8,22,57189,492,22,57188,8,492,57188,57189,1,1]%0A[6,4,4,6,4,7,4,7]%0A[2,2,2,2,2,2]%0A[5,1,4,5,1,1,4]%0A[77,31,5,31,80,77,5,8,8]%0A[1,2,3,2,1]%0A[44,4,4]%0A[500,30,1]%0A[1,2,1,1]%0A[2,4,6,4,4,4]&a=1&m=2)

**Algorithm:**

1. Sort array.
2. Get run-lengths.
3. Remove all `2`s from run-lengths.
4. Result is empty?

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 52 bytes

```
func[b][(extract sort b 2)= unique extract next b 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LDoMgELz7FXNsbwJr0Sb9iV4Jh/pKvNjWatK/pwtqihrYYXcGltmhqd29qY1NkvYK1059ZUprTs13HB7ViM9zGFFCnm@Y@u49NViVnhOvWPcaun5ECwMNoVBAQqQM5I9AEZM2@d8TrKoFN3zKOwTDkq7V5p5UIWIuh5TItMgLUCHXImfel3M@y2LX7cL@KKAOEWsyWjGfcQ8K6M9Y0RpKsMKQp77K4E0cx5c7G0TBx@YXnlwdhg8vxc4mLWNwA/cD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda x:set([x.count(i)for i in x])=={2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHPS8MwFL7nr8htDTxkTVOTDnoQUTx40nmQroe6taww29Fm0CH@7fWlabIJmpAv79f38l7e8az3bRONVboZD8Xnx66gw6ovdZANN9v21OigZlXb0ZrWDR1ylqZf/HvU3UnvzzSlGaG4MglhBAlwCJcIwlyTSUCSgw0J0RHBhN60xMDpIMzirPkQjhzuGQo4h1iGKgGRcKcoUJNqZevGfDnJCamKQ19eVXqLNQkwKM1xiTGX284UYw4BBvF2RikhCtGIoLBHiSK@/rtHfilfmMc8OcbOouvmTOhF5XNhhmFKP3Y1fv9i/fK2fnpfMGLGoMte3xd9aaZhh7CayDa2CpyfMc9/vHt@ffiLb7/mP/74Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>84</s> 83 bytes

```c
c['   '],r,*p,*s,*e;f(){for(p=s;p<e;)c[*p++]++;while(s<e)r=c[*s++]-2?1:r;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBhS8MwEP2c/opHQZY2GdtaGLqs7B/4wW9Si4xw1YBrS1IRLf3t9epUxiDJu7x3uXsXu3yxdppsuQCwqLTXaafToFMytUyGuvWyK4Lp9mQSW6adUpVS5uPVvZEMe0p8wWxgdpkdNjtvPPXvvoE34@SaHqeja2SCIRLzrafQP9tjoFDmVbmtIiEKDMNmrZHxnjH/jfP1qFlmU8OGlcv1L@Qatxp3f2c2jubcxzGyc0iHAmsDhz1yBqV@rIjA9IUXV2nQNaW2XER0nuvVMr4JT02swV@CA@L7NsYO8SOFOJmzVikeKBCPS6fWfyJdMenPvTlilkVpNXiw4L6orWHnh2M0ikhM3w)

`f()` returns 1 if the list is *not* a list of Noah, and 0 otherwise.

The variable `s` should point to the beginning of the array, and `e` should point to the end. Note that after `f()` is called, `c` must be reset to 0s before it can be called again. Also, this might not work on all computers, because I'm pretty sure multi-byte characters are implementation-defined, and it won't work if `INT_MAX < 100000`.

If I/O is *very* flexible, and outputting to a variable is enough, the `return r;` is unnecessary, and it can be reduced to 74 bytes.

De-golfed:

```c
int counts[100001], return_value;

int f(int *start, int *end) {
        int *ptr;
        for (ptr = start; ptr < end; ptr++)
                counts[*ptr]++;
        for (ptr = start; ptr < end; ptr++) {
                if (counts[*ptr] != 2) {
                        return_value = 1;
                }
        }
        return return_value;
}
```

Thanks to @ceilingcat for -1 byte!

Comment: Functions should preferrably be [reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable/4940#4940) without massaging external values.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 9 chars, 18 bytes

```
{⍵≡⍦,⍨∪⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵≡⍦,⍨∪⍵}
  f 7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9
1
  f 77,31,5,31,80,77,5,8,8
0
  f 2,4,6,4,4,4
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 66 bytes

```
f(n)=>n.map((m)=>n.where((o)=>o==m).length==2).reduce((p,e)=>p&e);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHLboMwELz3KywOjZFWKBgooIje2i/oLeKAElMihYdck6qq8u10MBioeqmQxzuzD3bgXCg9DCVv3Oy58eqi47w24WclleS8BWmzrHa9q2zedZVlwvWUPPcnJDuSSHeP0j0MdXFpuPv9wNitUOymWcaOIIwdY/IDSkmQvweE42WkkNKcphIfiYAMLtIeheYA5nBmS4lAj1g6EhKCothPUgpTYUlCiaFTPKUxL0dPfrDbluu2T9grpBHj8djhmGcfK0WYE9KIuK0YxxT4EAEJfMYIscFvn2K1EI4vW5ojuAu2BsfSlYp5sU0H1gko@CPQLE4mZ5dl38BmaXinLo3mzpvqdfXluOZDaK9s1UtxqjjX5kfaMjRCMUV3g5O8222I81pcP6QdVf5z1H34AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 45 bytes

```
:sor|%norm J
:g/^\v(.*) \1$/d
:g/./norm ggcG0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36o4v6hGNS@/KFfBi8sqXT8upkxDT0tTIcZQRT8FJKCnD5ZMT092N/j/35zL0JjLksuIy9AASJiAKLCQCVDQEgA)

This will output nothing for a valid Noah list, and a 0 for an invalid Noah list.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for testcases like `7 7 7 7`, but anyways, here's a solution at 33 bytes `:sor<cr>qq*djkj@qquG@qqar.ggcG0<esc>qu@a`

Comment: https://tio.run/##fVHbctowEH1mf6EvO5RJ2o5AyDKxnTppXpo89gMymcGVhe2EWL5SmNJvJytjUjKlGWvPXrV7vPoZ1elORc21CsPvP253l7WpoCy/xI9Pjzdl2d4RRNUkSdTd9EPZ3kQ7qoL1OkYFv9JsqbHSUYzZV4wNDLKr4eh3xjnj8GcIg4@YNk1RX3KuTKwTs1xM6iZST3qt0ihP9ESZZx5x4XvB7AIGNLoJw3A4yobbNs9KHKttUukCxys8RwfPr3msVzxvl0sY3N/jvNYxcsFjujT6NscrnBebJjW5g9wUDV/x5yjLJ8UGFY5bHC8w/FRUWd4s0M74PMeHh7MzrVKDG11vt52VG4hNrnceE5IFzGFiSuBa1YVcFoCgiGQdAsXFtBOC3uw9EA5VORJ85jhs5gk/YG7gHByf@Z27t/dp6gAXNMNlFj0rQBcOH8yowmUWSYPnMSnII/CJnkcmNe3pEXNwbScXZsRGdoRslLTTD7BJaiuZ/Gux3vPAY50ckDT9/@HAkWFtCST2SOj2JE@t7m1OyP0e5Ts1r/dfE6ffhF7lf9ngOH8q@y@pdykd05Zvql4A

Comment: 31 https://tio.run/##fVHbctowEH1mf6EvO5RJ2o5AyDKxnTopL20e@wGZzODKwnZCLF8pTOm305UxKZnSjLVnr9o9Xv2I6nSvouZWheHX79/217WpoCw/xY9Pj/OybO/mZVRNkkTdTd@188meamCziVHBzzRbaax0FGP2GWMDg@xmOPqVcc44/B7C4D2mTVPU15wrE@vErJaTuonUk96oNMoTPVHmmUdc@F4wu4IBDW7CMByOsuGuzbMSx2qXVLrA8Rov0cHLWx7rNc/b1QoG9/e4qHWMXPCYLo2@LPAGF8W2SU3uIDdFw9f8OcrySbFFheMWx0sMPxRVljdLtDM@LvDh4eJCq9TgVte7XWflBmKT673HhGQBc5iYErhWdSGXBSAoIlmHQHEx7YSgN3sPhENVjgSfOQ6becIPmBs4R8dnfuce7EOaOsAVzXCZRc8K0IXjBzOqcJlF0uB5TAryCHyi55FJTXt6xBxc28mFGbGRHSEbJe30A2yS2kom/1qs9zzwWCdHJE3/fzxwYlhbAok9Ero9yXOre50T8rBH@UbNy/2XxPk3oVf5XzY4zZ/L/kvqTUqntOWrqj8

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck: 69

```
->+[>+<-[[-]+>->>[-]]+>[->++[-<<<+]->>]<,]>>>[>>[--[[-]>>-<[-]<]]>]>.
```

The bf interpreter/compiler needs to support 0 as EOF. It also need at least 300003 cells for be be used with number upto 100000. `beef` seems to match this.

The numbers are expected to come in as unary (whatever) terminated by ascii 1. It will output chr 0 on a valid set and chr 99 on an invalid set. If your terminal has UTF-8 you'll get some complaints or a replacement chars (the ?) as an indication.

The code uses bf memory as the first cell as an -1 flag that it seeks to after every number. Each number triggers it to jump 3 cells, since I have a 3 cell item and the whole BF memory is considered an array:

```
flag (-1) [ visited | flag | count ]*
```

Thus if you supply 3 it will set count on the third index to 1 and every visited flags to 1 upto that.

I've tested like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
set -l tests '[7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9]
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
[10,100,1000,1,100,10,1000,1]
[123,123]
[8,22,57189,492,22,57188,8,492,57188,57189,1,1]
[6,4,4,6,4,7,4,7]
[2,2,2,2,2,2]
[5,1,4,5,1,1,4]
[77,31,5,31,80,77,5,8,8]
[1,2,3,2,1]
[44,4,4]
[500,30,1]
[1,2,1,1]
[2,4,6,4,4,4]
[2,23,34,4]
[2,23,3,3,34,4]
'

for in in (echo $tests)
  echo -n $in :
  echo $in | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/"1" x $1/ge;s/[^\]\d,]//g;s/(?:]|,)/\x01/g;' | beef  moses.bf
  echo ''
end
```

And got the following output:

```
[7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9] :
[1,2,3,1,2,3] :
[10,100,1000,1,100,10,1000,1] :
[123,123] :
[8,22,57189,492,22,57188,8,492,57188,57189,1,1] :
[6,4,4,6,4,7,4,7] :[Invalid UTF-8] \xff
[2,2,2,2,2,2] :[Invalid UTF-8] \xff
[5,1,4,5,1,1,4] :[Invalid UTF-8] \xff
[77,31,5,31,80,77,5,8,8] :[Invalid UTF-8] \xff
[1,2,3,2,1] :[Invalid UTF-8] \xff
[44,4,4] :[Invalid UTF-8] \xff
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <strike>46</strike> 45 bytes

```
fun f(l:IntArray)=l.all{l.count{i->it==i}==2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7BisMgFLznK6ahBz1UalJYWtbCHnvutRdZSJG1L8GahSJ@u/tiwz5wHN@bN@PPGL2jUoaZMAh/ulD8CsG@pNl4ZemVvPoeZ4rJ7c4uGuPyxnS5yh/WkbDh/jyhrnxeY3B0P0ukpgHXMAYsAjjColsGWOvXem5Pc4SpGvWcvIuiRSvVw05IcFHFkb8jJLJ80xoj5L/JxHm8s02DqF4y36iV7/DcNLkUjQ49KpYP6B5HpnrPcFiu2jrgWJjrfT0MK11fRXfs0PV/)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.1, 63 bytes

`let x={(a:[Int])in a.allSatisfy{v in a.filter{v==$0}.count==2}}`

When the `count(where:)` function will be available, it'll become:

`let x={(a:[Int])in a.allSatisfy{v in a.count{v==$0}==2}}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDPasMwDMbveQozdkhAlPhPaqeQB9i5x66HbItZIKQjdbuO0mfPZMVpC2PzCJbtTz/Jn7L/bK1T43isB@Y4q9hGA5dQggCeY1B@I0lBuU0IEx7jmJRAMciS5BwLaGEIx3ALmCJMYK2YKwsvGRACCs1NCaoU88WAoet0ntLc96JKS46X6E2Bj9qvqakll9hn/oJMLgvsocBH3EOCfGkNkmMCg8G5NR7RQSCK29xiHscuvai8gbmRphdwYnkd2pq5lF@lcvI3Gb9V8zz4liDvVH5TYc4kXePYqTqn9Wrz1Ltt1vasXtRdt65du7df5yMjxbada4bzsaoe88vidXfoXVWJyyVJPoa2d@nD@n136N7YS8PccGhW7Dk9pY5n2UP2JyGihIwSKkoURPxEbN3tA2N/8XqPiDgi44iKI0UcWcYRHUdMHCnjCM//wUz/dxy/AQ)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Four years and seven minor releases later, and `count(where:)` is still in purgatory because the type-checker couldn't handle it. Regardless, I think you can drop the `let x=` and the explicit type, so just `{a in a.allSatisfy{v in a.filter{v==$0}.count==2}}` would be a valid spelling of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 30 characters

```
group_by(.)|map(length==2)|all
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq 'group_by(.)|map(length==2)|all' <<< '[7,13,9,2,10,2,4,10,7,13,4,9]'
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@9KL@0ID6pUkNPsyY3sUAjJzUvvSTD1tZIsyYxJ@f//2gLHSMjHVNzQwtLHRNLIxjHQscCzIWwIdKGOoaxAA)

[Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCsIwEDzbrwieGliK2aQmVfwSFan4KFKf6EHov9fJo6KETHZ2Z7Jzuve7/UFcrnUz64@P6@u22b7zQnbn@pa3@8vx2SwWLLu6bft5lhWiE34yXuWiEFLMBApvFnIs@2U2WlpSmipiUhOA8U9oGarWhLlCV1PAyCeQhAtIZWJxzlBz1DpiptIqV5GpeCCOXKCxjmMV3LBMsdiQR@tv@AbO4QReQm7II97QsZa0QgfgkN@ixJaf/JzSGf979JSIrL@pvSLVnAIMQqzVpP8ZpU62/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

```php
for(;$n=$argv[++$i];$a[$n]++);echo min($a)==2&&max($a)==2;
```

Each number in the list is passed as an argument.

Outputs 1 for truthy and nothing for falsey.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8mxVEovSy6K1tVUyY61VEqNV8mK1tTWtU5Mz8hVyM/M0VBI1bW2N1NRyEyugbOv///8b/jf6bwwhAQ)

[Tests](https://tio.run/##bVJha4MwEP3urwglFFuFatSpy2Tf9gv2zUkJJauCWlE7VsZ@u7tconVsEpJ37@6eL0e6spuenruysyw6ymEcSEZyi8B32JPX/jqWt0eyPyCTxy7xA5ekLmGAPDxCjUwKorRwdbWPeSANWHhPtejNw6yJFmapZKqbLZ0JCIFSFPsJeAhTdo8hlRjKhKbK13rzlV5EPcjVlR7QMywNYr3PP2To/L5mPkJdqNRA4TkVg0TgY0YdiZpNjKGy@Gc2bHXdUDtZpCI1jODXQHTDimEr8@te5Rbkg/84vUym4Jb1fumlOJXENk9ADATRjnxhJxX9@QMehuh7cTs2sj9LO2@vdV24ppCbOvV6ChNUEHh8AnGb0zZDkdxxaFVwKnLaFo6z4/JUXkhTtTYVuyxj220jPg3mk5LBgs1bu@HW9/QD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 24 bytes

```arturo
$=>[[]=--values tally&2]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?UfeixZ)

```
$=>[        ; a function where input is assigned to &
    tally&  ; create a dictionary of counts of elements in input
    values  ; get just the counts
    --   2  ; remove all the twos
    []=     ; is it the empty list?
]           ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 40 bytes

```
f(L)=0^{[L[L=i].length-2fori=L]^2.total}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/avkigndwt4)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2srlndjpvt)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 4 bytes

```
SUu₌
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJTVXXigowiLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMSJd)

Sort, uninterleave, uniquify, check if equal

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 31 bytes

```perl
$k{$_}++}{$_=!grep$_-2,values%k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lu1olvlZbuxZI2SqmF6UWqMTrGumUJeaUpharZv//b8hlxGXMBSFNuUz/5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0@K9bkAMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 8 bytes

```
/×=2⊕⧻⊛.
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAgL8OXPTLiipXip7viipsuCiMgRXhwbGFpbmVkOgojIC_Dlz0y4oqV4qe74oqbLgojICAgICDiipXip7viipsuICMgTGlzdCBvZiBjb3VudHMKIyAvw5c9MiAgICAgIyBJcyBpdCBhbGwgMnM_CgpGIFs0IDQgNCA0IDYgNiA3IDddCkYgWzEgMiAzIDQgNCAzIDIgMV0K)

Answer (score 1):

## [Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 44 bytes

```
{++k[$0]}END{for(i in k)a=a||k[i]-2;print a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Wls7O1rFILbW1c@lOi2/SCNTITNPIVsz0TaxpiY7OjNW18i6oCgzr0Qhsfb/fwsuIyMuU3NDC0suE0sjGMeCywLMhbAh0oZchgA)

0 means it is a list of Noah, 1 means that it is not a list of Noah.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>36</strike> 32 bytes

```
++_[$0]-2{i++}END{print NR/i==2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fWzs@WsUgVteoOlNbu9bVz6W6oCgzr0TBL0g/09bWqPb/fyMuIy5jLmMA)

- -4 bytes, print value of `NR/i==2` assessment instead of using ternary operator.

Will print `1` for `List of Noah` and `0` for `not`.