# Ah, why is there a bug in my program?

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

This challenge is inspired by [@LuisMendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200008/75323) to my "[binary multiples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200008/75323)" challenge.

## Task

Pick a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge that is *open* and that has been posted *before* this one; let me call it the *"linked challenge"*. The *linked challenge* must be a challenge whose task involves producing output.

Write the shortest code possible that satisfies the following restrictions:

- Your code must contain the characters `b`, `u` and `g` in your program, in this order and consecutively (case-insensitive, so "bug", "BUG", "Bug", "bUg", ... are all fair game.);
- Your code must *not* contain the letters `b`, `u` and `g` more than once (case-insensitive);
- Your code should be a valid submission for the *linked challenge*;
- When any subset of the (case-insensitive) characters `bug` are removed, your program no longer fulfils the task of the *linked challenge*. This may happen because your program now produces the wrong output (i.e. fails test cases), because it halted with an error, because it runs indefinitely and never returns (if this is the case, be prepared to prove your program runs indefinitely), etc.
- Your code should not be an integral copy - nor a trivial modification<sup>*</sup> - of a submission that already exists in the *linked challenge* (for example, you may not copy [@LuisMendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200008/75323) to my "[binary multiples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200008/75323)" challenge);

## Input

Your program takes input as per the specs of the *linked challenge* you choose.

## Output

Your program, in its correct state (i.e. with a bug<sup>**</sup>), must abide by the output specs of the *linked challenge* you choose.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>This is subjective so I appeal to your common sense; any imaginative modification should be fair game, even if in retrospective it is "trivial". This "no trivial modifications" rule will be "enforced" by me downvoting answers I think disrespect this...</sub>

<sup>**</sup> <sub>Sit down, take a moment to let this sink in. Your program has a bug. And yet your program is correct.</sub>

## Posting an answer

When you post your answer, please provide a link to your *linked challenge*.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it! If you dislike this challenge, please give me your written feedback. Happy golfing!

Comment: @a'_' I do not understand how that challenge presents a loophole; can you please clarify?

Comment: @RGS Interesting challenge. I wonder if the challenge can be more focused by specifying just 1 linked challenge to solve. As of right now, my effort is divided between picking a linked challenge, and golfing/solving the linked challenge.

Comment: _your program now produces the wrong output_ -> I assume it's fine if the program is still producing the correct output for some inputs, but a wrong output for at least one input?

Comment: If there is a only a newline in between the characters, does that still count a 'consecutively'?

Comment: @Arnauld you assume correctly, will make it more clear

Comment: @ouflak nope, the three characters must be _really really_ consecutive :) so that they spell "bug" :)

Comment: @a'_' I imagine a Python solution to the "Do nothing challenge" is `x,y,z="bug"`

Comment: @SurculoseSputum I could arbitrarily pick a challenge, but I wanted to give you more freedom... Of course it comes at a cost! You have to pick a challenge..

Comment: But the consecutive letters 'bug' can have other consecutive letters around them, yes?

Comment: Yes yes, of course! They can even be part of a bigger word / function name / string / wtv.

Comment: If any of the people who downvoted would be so kind as to give me some feedback, I would be really pleased! :)

Comment: @JoKing The "posted before" was already in the specs; will add the bit about being open

Comment: It's impossible to do this in brainfuck...

Comment: Python has [a built-in constant called `__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=bug#__debug__) which is `True` by default. Removing some of its `bug` will obviously be an error. Though I can't find a suitable challenge for that...

Comment: There *might* be an esolang where a variation of `BUG` can solve [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/78410)...

Comment: @RGS The title of this question has affected other new users to think that we are another place for programming Q&A. For example, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201260/what-will-be-printed-by-the-following-program-segment-int-a-a-2-5-2030-1) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201261/why-is-the-array-skipping-a-iterratinon) (deleted) are low-quality posts that are affecting the quality of questions on this site. You really need to change the title.

Comment: @a'_' it is frequent, although unfortunate, to have new users post SO questions here; do you think this frequency has increased significantly because of my post? Either way, I am open to changing the title for something that induces less errors from newcomers, as long as it preserves the spirit of the current title. Do you have any suggestions? I haven't come up with anything nice yet.

Comment: @RGS Yes, the frequency is much higher after your post; there are already 2 posts with an interval of 15 minutes! Currently the only title I can think of is Why does my program contain the string "bug"?

Comment: Title suggestion: `The Correct Bug` which doesn't lead to confusion.

Comment: @a'_' I think the title right now is fine. If a new user cannot figure out the purpose/theme of the site, then that should be a problem of the UI anyway.

Comment: I give up. Tried to find a way to do this in Java, but it's impossible due to that source restriction of `bug`. I know [five different ways of creating a program in different versions of Java](https://pastebin.com/55PUYiXs), but none of them work here. Usually I could get around that by using `\u`-unicode escaped characters in the program, which works in other challenges where certain characters are banned, but since `u` is banned, that's not an option either.. Ah well, I tried.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen but I assume you can still write an arrow function or something, right? I think it is fair to say the source restrictions only show up in the part of the answer that usually goes in the `Code` section of TIO... Wouldn't you say so?

Comment: @RGS Hmm, a function is indeed possible. Was under the impression it required a full program. Will try to come up with a function in that case. :)

Comment: `When any subset of the (case-insensitive) characters bug are removed` suggest `non-empty subset`?

Comment: @S.S.Anne Actually, it may be possible using a [tag:restricted-source] or a [tag:self-referential] challenge

Comment: When you say a subset of `bug` will be removed, does that include the entire string `bug`?

Comment: @Shaggy yes, it does include. So your program may not work when the three letters B, U and G are removed from your program

Answer (score 19):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Challenge: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/84206)

```
BUG³
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QlVHsw)

### Explanation

`B`, `U`, and `G` are variables for 11, the input, and 16 respectively.

When applied to a number, `³` brings it to the third power.

In Japt, only the last expression is outputted, so only \$16^3 = 4096\$ is outputted, which is the same length as the code (4).

Since `B` and `U` are ignored, removing them have no effect on the output. However, their removal changes the length of the program, making it invalid. Removing `G` raises either the input (`U`) or 11 (`B`) to the third power. While \$11^3 = 1331\$ is 4 bytes, the program `B³` is only two bytes, making the output invalid. The variable `U` defaults to 0 when there is no input given, and \$0^3 = 0\$, which is only one byte long.

Comment: This seems like a pretty clever answer. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @ouflak the first version had a bug, I deleted it to give me some time to edit it

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance ba-dum crash!

Comment: Fail `³` also work

Answer (score 10):

## Polyglot,  31 bytes

Linked challenge: [“Hello, World!”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/58563)

This is a full program, as per the original challenge requirements.

```javascript
print('Hello, World'+'bug!'[3])
```

[Try it in JavaScript (V8)!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EQ90jNScnX0chPL8oJ0VdWz2pNF1RPdo4VvP/fwA)

[Try it in Python!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ90jNScnX0chPL8oJ0VdWz2pNF1RPdo4VvP/fwA)

[Try it in Ruby!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69EQ90jNScnX0chPL8oJ0VdWz2pNF1RPdo4VvP/fwA) (thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) for pointing this out)

Comment: This works in Ruby too.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES7), 47 bytes

Linked challenge: [How many petals around the rose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200386/58563)

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=>t+=n**3&parseInt('bug',35)%9,t=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFfS8MwFMXf@ynyok1nLetNGqaQiqDCcOAHKH2IsxvKTEdbB4Lfva4Njcc@9M@5Jzn53ZsPczLttnk/dte2fqv6ne6Nzk3yaY7c6ry70naxEJdH07TV2nY8fP3ah7HIooubuNPL6Kfrt7Vt60OVHOo9D4qiSGOWljFbnp9REApRusIoJDpZ6QqjUN4hTCNMI0wjTCNMI0wTLo0mQSiE3yPcj3eGNDUJ5R2JbBLZJLJJZJPIJpEtc2lyEoRCeILMVb0zpK0mobyjkE0hm0I2hWwK2dR8bjiGoQskHPpFf7hcTM78@pWfHAKKcX2KIxOz8@aDo9n@vyNS343D@NewGHfS6NHsztVUzdzbZZVBUp2q5pvzwsTMlhHTOdtxc/5qZqPgjoUvzyG7ZeHT/Xrz@BBG/S8)

#### How?

This is a port of [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200429/58563) to the linked challenge. This answer requires a bitwise AND with a constant, which happens to be \$6\$.

This \$6\$ is obtained with the cumbersome `parseInt('bug',35)%9` and removing any subset of characters from `bug` would produce a different (and therefore invalid) constant.

```
   s   | parseInt(s, 35) | mod 9
-------+-----------------+-------
 'bug' |      14541      |   6
 'ug'  |       1066      |   4
 'bg'  |        401      |   5
 'bu'  |        415      |   1
 'g'   |         16      |   7
 'b'   |         11      |   2
 'u'   |         30      |   3
 ''    |        NaN      |  NaN
```

Comment: `'bug'.length*2 ` is an alternative

Comment: @SurculoseSputum That's actually not possible: there's a 'g' in 'length'.

Comment: That's unfortunate :( I was thinking of Python when writing that comment.

Comment: `a=>a.map(n=>t+=n**3&('bug'[2]&&6),t=0)|t` for 40 bytes

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance There's also `&!!'bug'[2]*6` for 39 bytes, but I think I'll stick with my sub-optimal version for this answer, so feel free to use it in another one!

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 156 bytes

Answer to [99 bugs in the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165623/99-bugs-in-the-code). Not competitive, but funny.

```c
#define S"%d bugs in the code\n"
d;f(i){for(i=99;i;i=d)printf(S S"Take one down and patch it aro\x75nd\n"S"\n",i,i,d=(d=i+rand()%21-16)<0?0:d);printf(S,0);}
```

Also beats the C solution there.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzNCsIwEITveYqlUkiwhVZQqbH4EPXYS8wm7SImpcYfKH32mIszMMxh5tPloHWMGzSWnIEuyxFur@EJ5CCMBrRH07uMobScxGL9zKltGkmSWhTTTC5Y3qXfVd0N@IRA/3GgHMKkgh6BAqjZ99/j3mECdVmKgpKx5djSdk5TLvJdXdYHca4u1QmF/HOLSsg1pg4PRY6/PaFgC4Mky4Vka/wB)

Comment: +1 for the "right" challenge to solve.

Answer (score 5):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 6 bytes

Linked to Challenge: [Shortest code to produce infinite output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output)

```
bug>%<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/P6k03U7V5v9/AA)

Comment: Basically the same thing works in [Hexagony](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/z@pNL3O2uH/fwA), probably other layout languages, too.

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 16 bytes

Solving [Output programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name)

```php
echo'2=7'^'bug';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8tWNbM3V49STStPVrf/b2/0HAA)

Omitting any of the letters in `bug` outputs a wrong string. However, it won't cause any errors so that error messages containing `PHP` can never be outputted. All PHP answers in that challenge exploit either PHP flags, which cannot contain the word `bug`, or PHP errors, which omitting a letter from `bug` could still result in an output that fulfils the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
while __debug__:print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVIT4@JTWpND0@3qqgKDOvRMNQ8/9/AA)

*Linked challenge: [Shortest infinite loop producing output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

Uses the fact pointed out by @Bubbler:

> Python has a built-in constant called `__debug__` which is True by default. Removing some of its bug will obviously be an error. Though I can't find a suitable challenge for that...

Comment: Removing the `bu` from your answer still gives the correct answer -- the rules state that any subset of the characters in `bug` being removed should cause the problem to return something different, not just the bug as a whole!!

Comment: @ValueInk I changed the language and used python instead.

Comment: Quoting my spec, `"The linked challenge must be a challenge whose task involves producing output."`

Comment: @RGS that's been fixed now. I've really lost the ability to read challenges today. :P

Comment: I really like the use of `__debug__`, however simply using `"bug"[2]` should be shorter (and more boring). [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/vzwjMydVKak0XSnaKNaqoCgzr@T/fwA).

Comment: So de-bugging \_\_debug\_\_ gives you an error to debug?

Comment: @user253751 yeah, that's pretty much the case. Ironic, isn't it! :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) and perhaps a polyglot in concept, <s>25</s> <s>28</s> 32 bytes

Along the lines of Arnauld's answer, linked to challenge [Output programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name).

```lua
print('\076\117\097 5.'..#'bUg')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDPcbA3CzG0NA8xsDSXMFUT11PT1k9KTRdXfP/fwA)

*Added 3 bytes Thanks to @RGS spotting the 'u' in 'Lua'*
*Added 4 bytes Thanks to @MariaMiller for the 'L' and the 'a' as well*

Comment: This is not a valid answer because the letter "u" appears twice in your code!

Comment: @RGS, Oh my God. You're right! Let me fix this up.

Comment: It still uses L, u, and a. This answer won't work for Lua, as you need a u for bug, but you can't use a u since it's in L**u**a.

Comment: @MariaMiller, Refresh your browser. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment, RGS already pointed that out and I've already updated the answer.

Comment: According to the linked kata, your code cannot include **any** characters of the language's name, but case sensitive so it can be fixed: You can fix `L` and `a` with the same way you fixed `u`, and I just noticed that you can change `bug` to `bUg` or `BUG` or whatever and this will be alright. Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: Didn't they realize that both `l` and `A` aren't banned in outputting the language name? [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDPSfGwtRRwVRPXU9PWT0pNF1d8/9/AA)

Comment: @a'_', It's a little bit trickier balancing the rules between two challenges than I thought it would be. Especially as they both have multiple subtle restrictions. Think I'll just stick with the 'safest' interpretation of both/either.

Comment: There's a lowercase `u` in `bug` that's also in `Lua`. You need to get rid of it or it's not valid.

Comment: @S.S.Anne, Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 bytes

Solves [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/78410).

```apl
×'BUG'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P/h6epOoe7qIM7/AgA)

Prints `1 1 1\n`, 6 bytes in total.

In regular APL, monadic `×` is Signum for numbers (-1 if negative, 1 if positive, 0 if zero). Extended provides an extended (no pun intended) definition for characters (-1 for lowercase, 1 for uppercase).

Because numeric arrays are printed with a space between items, deleting one char out of `BUG` will remove two bytes (`<space>1`) from the output, thus failing to solve the challenge. Deleting two chars will remove four output bytes, and deleting all of them gives only a single newline.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/)/[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)/others, 15 bytes

Challenge: [Output with same length as code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

```sh
echo BUG{1..3}
```

[Try it online (Zsh)!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX8Ep1L3aUE/PuJbr/38A)
[Try it online (Bash)!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BKdS92lBPz7iW6/9/AA)

Comment: The second submission is invalid because the _linked challenge_ should produce output!

Comment: Argh, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

Challenge: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

It's working. But I still didn't manage a 3-byte solution.

```
BUG^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3ynUPe7/fwA)

## Why it works

```
B    "Constant for 11";
 U   "Constant for 0";
  G  "Constant for 16";
   ^ "Bitwise XOR";
```

0 XOR 16 is 16, therefore it outputs `1116`.

## Removing a single character

```
UG^
```

It just outputs `16` without other calculations.

```
BG^
```

It outputs `27` because 11 XOR 16 is 27.

```
BU^
```

It outputs `11` because 11 XOR 0 is 0.

### Removing 2 characters

CJam doesn't have implicit input, so all these programs would throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

[Create output twice the length of the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59436/create-output-twice-the-length-of-the-code)

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
╘╘BUG]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1BlA5BTqHvv/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Linked challenge: [Output with same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/84206).

*Port of [Embodiment of Ignorance's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201227/6484).*

```
bugт
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/qTT9YtP//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 24 bytes

This one for real.

Answer to [Swap the parity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118819/swap-the-parity).

```c
f(x){x=-(-x^!"bug"[3]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7tasMwDPzvp7hlFOxW2dql@4C0fZEsg9RxUsPmDNsZYSHPntktlDL9OKST7nQybaWc54YPYhz2KU@Hj7vk2LdJkZUin@Z7beRnXyvsnK9193A6MKaNx1elDXjsKttKgjxVFstlGH4EGxlCxaVXzsvKKVeU2GPEhvBEyAhbwjPhhfBKeAvMJouwxZRftfrSNp0Nj4J6nUNjB@70r@oafrUWeMR/rliXQoT71UrgkibWtw2@DU8WNdIDFvW7Segmoi4Jtx46epzF0xmt8r01IQeb5j8)

Comment: [Your code work because format string is just placed after `"bug"`, or to say your solution relies on existance of `printf`](https://tio.run/##XY7taoMwFIb/5yreWQpJjaud3QfY9kbUgYuxDWxxJLHIxGu3SQvd2PlxOF/vc16RHIWY55YObBz2CU2G94foo4@KrGL5NC@UFp99I7GzrlHd4@lAiNIOX7XSoKGqzVFwiFNtsFr55szISOAjLJ20TtRW2qLCHiM2HE8cGceW45njheOV481PNllIW0z5XatuZdsZ/8ir0xwKO1CrfmTX0juaYY3/syKtGPP3ccxwcxPi23huS6MyLdNlg@SAZVPqKPaWfpWq4vhLUoF0RUzXbKTrjfZuyDRfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 26 bytes

Answer to [Shortest code to produce infinite output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output)

```c
f(){printf("bug"+2)&&f();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQympNF1J20hTTQ0oaF37HyiokJuYmadRlp@ZoslVzaUABCAprtr/AA)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your TIO link produces no output

Comment: @RGS I forgot the footer. Hang on...

Comment: Woops, I only noticed now... The character `u` shows up twice in your answer!

Comment: @RGS Fixed.....

Comment: why `&&`? then .

Comment: @l4m2 That was originally so it didn't produce any output if the string was modified. I might be able to remove it, but it's an old challenge and it only saves two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 8 characters

Linked question: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code/121521#121521)

```js
bug=>1e7
```

Outputs `10000000`, which has the same length as the program. Removing 1 or 2 characters would make it print the same thing, but wouldn't match the length of the program anymore. Removing all 3 is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

**[Reverse Bit Order of 32-bit Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36213/reverse-bit-order-of-32-bit-integers)**

```
%Ø%BUGƇḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/18AxVp1D3Y@0Pd7T8//9f19LCxMLAyNLADAA)

I managed to find a challenge that actually uses two of the letters in a productive way.

There's no Jelly answer to the challenge at the time of writing this answer.

### Explanation

```
%Ø%BUGƇḄ Main monadic link
%        Modulo
 Ø%        2^32
   B     Convert to binary
    U    Reverse
      Ƈ  Filter by
     G   Format as a grid
       Ḅ Convert from binary
```

Answer (score 1):

Linked to challenge: [Find the number of integers in the range from 1 to N that ends with 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200363/9481)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>95</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>39</s></sup> 35 bytes

Saved a byte (in a previous version) thanks to [Maria Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/maria-miller)!!!
Saved a byte (in an other previous version) thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!!!

```python
def f(n):print((n+len("bug")+5)/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcs7DoAgDADQ3VM0TG0Y/IWF22ik2MQUQnDw9NW4veXVp59FF7MjMTAqxdpEO6L6Kym6/c6OfKBxnsi4NBAQhbZpTrgGigPAH0A@MQrZCw)

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0fTqqAoM69EI9pIS8NIKyc6M1YbSKgagSl9o1hN3bqcaIvYtPwihUyFzDwgLzVPQympNF1JU8dUx0zHPFbzf46CrUK0JZBjqGOkY2ikY6JjbKpjaKFjbBTLBbLiPwA)

Comment: @MariaMiller Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQfacYXM1g0A83QodRUhuwUcQWnd7eq1@/i@xjxDO7x18OxKLoHASVf5MibWjZ1hFLAwYWaE5SwMOQnQBqY@nAM0RkGj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

Linked to [Find the number of integers in the range from 1 to N that ends with 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200363/find-the-number-of-integers-in-the-range-from-1-to-n-that-ends-with-2)

```ruby
->n{(n+5+"bug".size)/10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWiNP21RbKak0XUmvOLMqVVPf0KD2v7GpXklmbmqxQkq@Qk1mDZeCQkFpSbGCknJ1Zq2CcnWankamZq0SV2peyn8A)

Comment: What is the challenge this problem is linked to?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted it. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Linked to challenge: [Find the number of integers in the range from 1 to N that ends with 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200363/9481)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>51</s> <s>42</s></sup> 40 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=0;n+=2,"bug"[i++];);n/=10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrNCoMwDADge58iFISEVKYbO2X1RZwHrVRyWByyncRn736uH1@ql5RKUclotOd1Q42NGMdz8NN78b0yD0Jip9g2cpTHqIa0u/@0F/y23i5XYVZyAM/tqxl9NUPdQTXfzQcNkFGJxB3lAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

Linked Challenge: [How many petals around the rose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200386/how-many-petals-around-the-rose)

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=>t+=n**3&!!'bug'[2]*6,t=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFfS8MwFMXf@ymyF9PWWtabNAwhFUEFUfADlDzE2Q1lpmOrA8HvXteGxmMf@ufck5z87s2HPdnj@vC@765c@9b0G91bXdn80@5jp6vuUrs0FReLBX/92vKaTKqyTi@Tn65ft@7Y7pp8127jqK7rImOFydjy/IyCUAjjC6OQ6JTGF0ahgkOYRphGmEaYRphGmCZ8Gk2CUIiwR/if4AxpahIqOBLZJLJJZJPIJpFNIlvp0@QkCIUIBKWvBmdIW01CBUchm0I2hWwK2RSyqfnccAxDF0g49Iv@cLmYXIb1qzA5BBTj@gJHJmbnzQdHs/1/RxShG4/xr2Ex7qTRo9mdq6la@rfPMlHenJrDdxzXNmPOJExXbBPb81czl0Q3jL88cXbN@MPt4/P9HU/6Xw)

Originally posted as [a golf to Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201217/ah-why-is-there-a-bug-in-my-program/201218?noredirect=1#comment478744_201218).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 13 bytes

Solves [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/78410).

```python
print 'bug'*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQT2pNF1dy@T/fwA)

Prints `bugbugbugbug\n`.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

Solves [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/78410)

```python
print'bugHello, World!'[3:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EPak03SM1JydfRyE8vygnRVE92tgq9v9/AA)

Removing some of `bug` will chop off characters from the beginning of `'Hello, World!'`.

Comment: The middle answer isn't valid because the _linked challenge_ has to produce output!

Comment: I mean in my spec :) you have to pick a challenge where you have to produce output `"The linked challenge must be a challenge whose task involves producing output."`

Comment: @RGS Oops, sorry, I missed the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Challenge: [Output the same length as code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

```
BUG"2*
```

Repeats the string "BUG" multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 18 bytes

Challenge: [Output programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name/108201#108201)

(Joke ruiner over here, never mind.)

This errors (outputting the language name) when the bug is inside, and it doesn't error when any part of the bug is removed.

If you think that this uses the `i` character (taken from the question):

> Note that this is case sensitive. I can still use the char 'b' because it's different from 'B'.

```
if("bug"size>2,iO)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z8zTUMpqTRdqTizKtXOSCfTX/P/fwA)

### Explanation

```
        size       // Is the length of
   "bug"           // the string "bug"
            >2     // larger than 2?
if(           ,    // If so,
               iO  // Access an undefined variable
                 ) // Otherwise, do nothing
```

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 19 bytes

Challenge: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

```
"bug"at(2)cos print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//18pqTRdKbFEw0gzOb9YoaAoM6/k/38A)

## Explanation

```
"bug"               // The sequence "bug"
     at(2)          // The 3rd index of that
                    // (Out-of-bounds indexing returns nil)
                    // This returns an integer for an in-bound index
          cos       // Find the cosine of that
                    // (Cosine over nil throws an error)
              print // Print that value to STDOUT. (WITHOUT a newline)
```

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 19 bytes

Challenge:[Shortest infinite loop producing no output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output)

```
while("bug"at(2),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//788IzMnVUMpqTRdKbFEw0hTx0Dz/38A)

## Explanation

```
      "bug"         // Base string "Bug"
           at(2)    // Try to access the 3rd item of the string
                    // (Out-of-bounds returns nil)
while(          ,   // While that's true:
                    // (So a string is always true and nil is always false)
                 0) // No action needed
```

Comment: What does the last one solve?

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

Solves [I double the source, you double the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/78410)

```
>:Debug
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7axcUpNK0/9r/k8DAA) [Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7axcUpNK06HUf83/aQA)

Prints 1 as given, 2 doubled.

#### How it works

Monadic `>:` is "increment" (add 1), dyadic `>:` is "greater or equal" (`x >= y`).

```
>:Debug    NB. increment 0; gives 1

>:Debug>:Debug
  Debug>:Debug    NB. 0 >= 0; gives 1
>:                NB. increment it; gives 2
```

---

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

Solves [Output with the same length as code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/78410).

```
echo 6#Debug
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/BTNklNak0/f9/AA)

Somewhat similar to Python, J has a stdlib variable `Debug` which is initialized to the number 0. `6#` replicates the zero 6 times, and `echo` prints it. The output formatting is identical to APL's (space-separated numbers), so the output is `0 0 0 0 0 0\n`.

Being a terse language, I suspect there could be a more suitable challenge for J which gives a shorter solution using `Debug`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>88</s> 87 bytes

Linked challenge: [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime)
Given a number, outputs truthy/falsey depending on whether it is a prime number.

```java
n->{int i="BUG".charAt(2)-70;for(;n%++i%n>0;);System.console().printf("%s",""+(n==i));}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XZBPa8IwGMbvfoqHQCGhWusug2UVtsvYYe7gdho7xDTOuPqmNNExpJ@9S7VMMIeE98@TH8@zVQc12Zbfna6U93hRlo4jwFIwzVppg0VfAgdnS2ge@yAhY6sdxcsHFazGAoQC0@ny1wezy7Qj7yrDBTbKY2UMoTF1FX8r8WPDBsOe24cxvKVIuUisB7kAv69r14SocIS359eOJvNjT7cFe3x/YpneqOYh8Bsxuc3l2jVcUpKmNqF5LoW8ELK6ibI1Z4lnY8ZSTkVhhZBtJ3sH9X5VRQeDkZPLXcyAL0OUfX18QolzAD3izJ9J2PtilufxTdNhDFwjuU3ZHdgprP5QFuP7r663K@LDrD2F23Z/) (Note: `System.console()` is `System.out` on TIO, since TIO doesn't support console).

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  int i=            //  Integer `i`, starting at:
    "BUG".charAt(3) //  Get the third character from String `"BUG"` as unicode value
     -70;           //  and subtract 70 from it, so it'll become 1
  for(;n%++i        //  Increase `i` by 1 first before every iteration with `++i`
            %n>0;); //  And loop as long as `n` modulo-`i` is not 0
                    //  NOTE: The second `%n` is to stop the loop for input n=1
  System.console().printf("%s",
                    //  Print to STDOUT with String format:
    ""+(            //   Convert the following boolean to String:
        n==i));}    //   Check if `n` and `i` are equal
```

Prime checker credit goes to [*@SaraJ*'s answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181611/52210), which is rather ingenious.

Things I had to do to comply to the challenge:

1. The challenge description mentions program (and technically the linked challenge as well), but this isn't possible in Java. I know [five different ways](https://pastebin.com/55PUYiXs) of creating a full program in Java, but each of them requires at least one of the letters `bgu`. Usually I can get past source-restrictions by using `\u`-unicode escapes, but since `u` is one of the restricted characters that's also not an option here. Luckily OP allowed functions as well, which is (much) shorter anyway.
2. I couldn't use `return` since it contains an `u`. And I also couldn't use `System.out.print(...)`, since it contains an `u` as well. So instead, I use [`System.console().printf("format",...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))
3. Since I wanted to print a boolean, the format to use in the `printf` would be `"%b"`. Unfortunately, `b` is blocked, so instead I use `"%s"` and convert the boolean to a string.
4. And last thing to tackle was of course sneaking `bug` in, so it works with it, but doesn't work anymore without it. I've done this by changing the `int i=1;` to `int i="BUG".charAt(2)-31;`, which grabs the third character in the String (the `'G'`) as unicode value (`71`), and subtracts 70 from it to make it `1`. If any of the `B`, `U`, and/or `G` is removed, the `.charAt(2)` will fail with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Kevin, I fear you missed something very important: as soon as any `part` of `"bug"` is removed, your program should no longer work. So assigning it as variable somewhere doesn't really work, because having `bu=0` still works...

Comment: @RGS Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 15 bytes

Linked challenge: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

```r
strrep("bug",5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikqCi1QEMpqTRdScdU8/9/AA)

(or [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikqCi1QEMpqTRdT09PScdI8/9/AA) if we include the default `[1] ""` formatting with which [R](https://www.r-project.org/) surrounds its ouput, but this restriction did not seem to be applied to the original linked challenge).

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 11 bytes

Linked challenge: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

```
@echo %bug%
```

Outputs `ECHO is on.` when run regularly or when some of `bug` is removed, and outputs `%` when all of `bug` is removed.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (82 characters)

Linked challenge: [Integer lists of Noah](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187879/integer-lists-of-noah)

```js
c=>eval('O\x62ject').keys(x={},c.map(a=>x[a]=(x[a]||0)+1)).some(z=>x[z]!=2)&&'bug'
```

It's a bit lame, but I'm defining my outputs as producing 'bug' when input list is not a Noah list, and `false` when it is.

I love this challenge though. Maybe I can find a better solution. :)

Comment: Wait, I didn't notice the `b` in `Object` until now. doh.

Comment: I'm glad you like my challenge :D Like you noted, "Object" has an extra "b"; ping me when you find a valid solution!

Comment: I assume that escape sequences are allowed, so `eval("O\x62ject")` should be able to replace `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 6 bytes

Linked challenge: [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code)

```
BUG
ᴇ5
```